# Searchkick query on has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have an Organiser model, which has `has_many :events`. The model looks like the following:

```
class Organiser < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :delete_all

  scope :search_import, -> { includes(:events) }
  searchkick searchable: [:name]

  def search_data
    {
      name: name,
      category: category
    }
  end
end
```

The Event model has a `starts_on:datetime` column and I'd like to filter the organisers if it has an event within a date period. How would I achieve this?

### EDIT

I've got this working by adding the following to the `search_data` method:

```
   events: events.map{|event| {starts_on: event.starts_on} }
```

and then in the `search` method you can do the following:

```
  where: {"events.starts_on" => {gt: Time.now}}
```

Seems to work well. If there is a better way of doing this then please mention it.

Comment: The only difference to how I'd typically approach this would be to use the following in your `search_data` method: `events: events.as_json(only: [:starts_on])`

Pretty much the same, but makes it a little bit easier if you want to index other attributes from the association later.

Note, if you want to filter by a date range, you can use:

`where: {"events.starts_on" => (date_range_start..date_range_end)}`

Comment: You should answer your own question. That way you help the community by highlighting the answer and indicating that this problem was solved. Also you'll get points ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working by adding the following to the search_data method:

`events: events.map{|event| {starts_on: event.starts_on} }`

and then in the search method you can do the following:

`where: {"events.starts_on" => {gt: Time.now}}`